# Why isn't my refrigerator getting cold?

Tags: appliances, refrigerator

My compact fridge doesn't get cold, 
the motor is still running. Ice built up in
the freezer part. I defrosted it, and hit it with a hammer to remove the ice.
Then I hit something , some kind of
smoke or gas appeared.
Can I repair it?

Comment: umm...usually when you hit an appliance with a hammer to the point of seeing smoke it's likely dead.

Comment: use a bigger hammer to fix it!

Comment: That smoke was the refrigerant.  it is toast!

Answer (score 2):

Alas, the refrigerator is dead.

That smoke was the refrigerant escaping.  Theoretically, you can patch the hole or holes and recharge it.  But that will cost more to get right than buying a new one.

Next time you need to defrost, turn it off and let the ice melt.  This will take an hour or two at no risk to the refrigerator.  If you need to do it in minutes instead of hours, use a hair dryer.

Comment: For a full-sized fridge it might make sense to recharge the refrigerant, depending on its age and how much a replacement would cost. But for a mini fridge, forget about it.

Comment: @HenryJackson that's not counting getting to the ruptured pipe and repairing it